# How to get working set memory from a SYSTEM process

Tags: powershell

I am fairly unexperienced in powershell and I need to pull the memory usage from a process that falls under the SYSTEM user while logged in under my user in Windows Server 2012.

I can pull the information from my user easily but there is a large discrepancy from that and what it shows in task manager under the SYSTEM user.

The goal is to stop the java.exe process if it is using a certain amount of memory as shown below.

```
$java = Get-Process “java”  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (!$java.WS/1GB -gt 20) {
    $java | Stop-Process -Force}
```

However, when I run

```
(Get-Process "java").WS/1GB
```

I get ~1.364GB when the process under the system user in task manager is using ~173GB.

Comment: What's the exact column name you are looking in the task manager ?

Comment: When negating a condition with `!` it is very easy to forget enclosing the condition in braces. Your **if** condition now is wrong. Correct would be `if (!($java.WS/1GB -gt 20)) {$java | Stop-Process -Force}`. However, this returns `$false` when java uses more than 20 Gb, so I guess you mean `if ($java.WS/1GB -gt 20) {$java | Stop-Process -Force}`. Also, it is better to use straight quotes `"` instead of the curly ones or in this case no quotes at all.

Comment: It sounds like you are using the "Memory" column in Task Manager's Processes tab to gauge the processes memory usage. I would suggest using the "Working set (memory)" column in the details tab as a visual reference for memory usage. I've never been able to get a clear answer as to what the "Memory" column is measuring so I try not to rely on it. Please answer Sage Pourpre's question in the above comment.